# Degree of a rational function on Riemann sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Suppose we have a rational function $f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ on the Riemann sphere, where $p,q$ are polynomials with no repeated roots, would the degree simply be the sum of the polynomial degrees of $p$ and $q$? (Sorry, I'm being silly here, I forgot the definition of degrees using local degrees.)

I'm thinking that if we consider local degrees, for each root $z_i$ of $p(z)$ of multiplicity $k$, the local degree at $z_i$ should be $k$ as $f(z)$ basically just wraps around $k$ times around $z_i$.

If $z_i$ is instead a root of $q(z)$, then the local degree of $(z-z_i)^{-k}$ should still be $k$, since we are mapping $0$ to $\infty$ which is a reflection, causing $(-1)\times(-k)=k$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: What is the degree of $(z+1)/z$, for example?

Comment: Oh wait I'm being silly, the inverse image of 0 is just roots of $p(x)$ if degree of $p$ is larger than or equal to $q$, is the roots of $p(x)$ and $\infty$ if the degree of $p$ is less than the degree of $q$. So the degree should be the max degree of p and q?

Comment: There you go. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting rusty on this.